# Android Widget - Weird "loading Widget" error

Tags: android, widget

I am having a weird problem with my configurable clock widget I´m not being able to debug :(
This is my first Widget an it´s an easy one ;), It´s a background configurable clock widget.
   When the user selects the widget the configuration activity is launched. In this activity the user may choose the clock´s widget background. When the user finishes the configuration a "standard clock widget" with the user´s background appears on the launcher´s screen and that´s all. 
   I tested it thoroughly and it seems to works right till...
   The problem I´ve got it´s that from time to time when I turn on and unlock the screen, my widget it´s "gone" and I´ve got a grey box with the dreaded "Problem loading Widget" error on it :(
   So, I´ve got an error that I can´t get a reproducible scenario for it, maybe a life-cycle widget method error related?
   When the error appears I see no problem in the logcat so I´m completely lost.

This is the easy code for this widget: (GB 2.3.3). I´ve taken out not important bits.

1.- Widget Provider xml

```
<appwidget-provider xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:minHeight="190dp"
android:minWidth="170dp"
android:configure="......"
android:initialLayout="@drawable/......"
android:updatePeriodMillis="30000" >
</appwidget-provider>
```

2.- AndroidManifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="........"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="10"
    android:targetSdkVersion="10" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >

    <activity
        android:name="........"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.appwidget.action.APPWIDGET_CONFIGURE" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <receiver android:name="........." >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.appwidget.action.APPWIDGET_UPDATE" />
        </intent-filter>

        <meta-data
            android:name="android.appwidget.provider"
            android:resource="@xml/........" />
    </receiver>
</application>
</manifest>
```

3.- Widget Layout 
   I´ve got several widget layouts.The user selects one from the configuration activity
All the layouts are almost identical with minor changes (ImageView drawable):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/LinearLayout01"
android:layout_width="160dp"
android:layout_height="200dp"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<ImageView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
    android:scaleType="fitXY"
    android:src="@drawable/...." />

<AnalogClock
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="138dp"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom"
    android:dial="@drawable/...."
    android:hand_hour="@drawable/...."
    android:hand_minute="@drawable/...." />
</FrameLayout>
```

4.- Widget Provider (Java)

```
public class ClockProvider extends AppWidgetProvider {
public static int anoEscudo; 

@Override
public void onUpdate(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager, int[] appWidgetIds) {
    super.onUpdate(context, appWidgetManager, appWidgetIds);

    RemoteViews remoteView = null;
    for (int appWidgetId : appWidgetIds) {
        // Actualizamos la variable para luego poder modificar el fondo
        switch (anoEscudo) {
        case (...):
            remoteView = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout....);
            break;
        ...
        }

        appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(appWidgetId, remoteView);
    }
}
}
```

5.- Configuration Activity (Java)

```
package ...;

public class ConfigurationActivity extends Activity {
private int appWidgetId;

ImageView escudo;
TextView descripcion;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);     

    // get the appWidgetId of the appWidget being configured
    Intent launchIntent = getIntent();
    Bundle extras = launchIntent.getExtras();
    appWidgetId = extras.getInt(AppWidgetManager.EXTRA_APPWIDGET_ID, AppWidgetManager.INVALID_APPWIDGET_ID);

    // set the result for cancel first
    // if the user cancels, then the appWidget
    // should not appear
    Intent cancelResultValue = new Intent();
    cancelResultValue.putExtra(AppWidgetManager.EXTRA_APPWIDGET_ID, appWidgetId);
    setResult(RESULT_CANCELED, cancelResultValue);

    // show the user interface of configuration
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_configuration);

    // Setting configuration Activity graphical elements
    // ..
}

//Changing the Widget configuration
private void ... (View view) {      
    switch (escudoSeleccionado) {
    case 1:
        ClockProvider.anoEscudo = ...;
        break;
    ...
    }
}

// Finish the configuration Activity
public void ... (View view) {
    Intent resultValue = new Intent();
    resultValue.putExtra(AppWidgetManager.EXTRA_APPWIDGET_ID, appWidgetId);
    setResult(RESULT_OK, resultValue);

    new ClockProvider().onUpdate(this, AppWidgetManager.getInstance(this), new int[] { appWidgetId });

    finish();
}   
}
```

Comment: Did you debug this application?

Comment: What methods have you attempted to figure out what's happening? What results did you get from those methods? We can't suggest things without knowing what you've already tried, otherwise we'll just be retreading the same ground.

Comment: I don´t know how to use the debugger with a widget. I tested it in my mobile and it´s working find till some kind of life-cycle events make it show the "Problem Widget loading text" error. The error happens after leaving the mobile (and widget) running for some hours and you turn on the screen.

Answer (score 0):

- It may be related to updatePeriodMillis look at the [doc.](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/appwidgets/index.html) for updatePeriodMillis

> The updatePeriodMillis attribute defines how often the App Widget framework should request an update from the AppWidgetProvider by calling the onUpdate() callback method. The actual update is not guaranteed to occur exactly on time with this value and we suggest updating as infrequently as possible—perhaps no more than once an hour to conserve the battery. You might also allow the user to adjust the frequency in a configuration—some people might want a stock ticker to update every 15 minutes, or maybe only four times a day.

if that not the case i recommend to look into the following references

- Android App Widget with Configuration Activity 

   [link 1](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/appwidgets/index.html#Configuring) , [link 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13694186/how-to-create-an-app-widget-with-a-configuration-activity-and-update-it-for-the)
- [Tutorial](http://wptrafficanalyzer.in/blog/android-app-widget-with-configuration-activity/) creating a similar app.